# (Some) security perms in WinXP corrupted (shows GUID instead of username)

Tags: windows, permissions

I've been using my Win XP machine (part of a domain) over the holiday period, so until yesterday it hadn't rebooted for about five days. I used it yesterday perfectly fine and shut it down. When I switched it on this morning the majority (but not all) of my shortcut links in the Quick Launch toolbar showed as generic file icons. If you open the folder and get properties on one of the failing shortcuts it says ''Target type: This is not a valid shortcut''.

Then in Outlook I noticed my signature wasn't showing (I checked my sent folder and the sig was ok yesterday). Checking the signature folder, I can't see the security tab on any of the sig files, and I have an access denied message on trying to open them. I can see the security tab on the signature folder itself, just none of the contents. If I try and use the parent folder's security tab and ''Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries shown here that apply to child objects'' it appears to work fine, but makes no actual difference. I logged in as administrator and saw that the owner of the files showed up as a GUID (clearly should've been my account in its place).

Any ideas what might have made that happen? So far I haven't heard any similar complaints from anyone else at the office...

**Edit:** I was also having problems using WAMP (permissions again). I've added my account as a member of the local administrators group on my machine and things work again, but I'd still be interested in any ideas as to what was going on. At the beginning of December we replaced our old server with a new one, creating a new domain and new user accounts. I think I was having problems specifically with files which were created by my old account (before the migration). But I've been using this machine regularly for about a month since the new server came, so it's strange to see issues now, no?

**Edit2:** Looking through the server logs, here's the only things I could find that seem remotely pertinent.

**System**

*(9:20am)*

> *Warning USER32 1073*: The attempt to unknown COMP023 failed [wtf?]

**Application**

*(When I logged off yesterday, and a few times since)*

> *Warning Userenv 1517*: Windows saved user PEDALOLTD\Andy registry while an application or service was still using the registry during log off. The memory used by the user's registry has not been freed. The registry will be unloaded when it is no longer in use.
>
> This is often caused by services running as a user account, try configuring the services to run in either the LocalService or NetworkService account.

*(First login today)*

> *Warning Folder Redirection 301*: Folder redirection policy application has been delayed until the next logon  because the group policy logon optimization is in effect.

Comment: When you say you moved from an old server to a new one what exactly do you mean? This now sounds more like the domain infrastructure itself is having issues, it would be a good idea for someone to check out the health of the DC's just in case it isn't just an issue affecting you alone. Many issues like this only become obvious to end users once systems reboot, and potentially associate with new\different DC's so even though problems may not appear to be widespread initially there can be a system wide issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Sorry, have tried to clear that up a bit. There's been plenty of reboots since the new system was installed, so I don't know what sparked it off this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the account GUIDs aren't resolving the most likely issues are network connectivity with the domain controllers or your machine's account in the domain has been removed\changed.

Checking the system Event Log for errors\warnings relating to the domain would be a good place to start and should give you a clearer picture about what has gone wrong.

As a first step I'd check that all the network connections are OK, make sure you are on a wired network if at all possible and do a full reboot. If you have domain credentials that allow you to add your machine into the domain then if the reboot doesn't work try removing the machine from the domain and rejoining to eliminate the possibility that it's machine account related.

Comment: Thanks. I _think_ the reason the GUID isn't resolving is because it refers to an account on the previous server. (The question I guess then becomes why I could use my machine for the last month with no problems). I'll add the little bit of info that's in the logs to the main post. Network seems to be working fine: I've logged on and off multiple times, used files from the network (in fact I have redirected folders that seem to be working just fine). I also reset my machine more than once before posting this question. I don't fully understand the last bit of your answer :/